# Click on collectionView go to another collectionView with different array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I am fairly new to swift and there was a question that I wanted to ask.

I have three ViewControllers the first two have collection views on them and the last one doesn't.

I have it so that the first controller displays two arrays within the collection view. The first being a string array, and the second an image array, this is so that they line up correctly on the collection view.

This what I am struggling to understand. How do I, when a collection view cell is clicked, have it then go to the second controller (Where there is another collection view) and display a completely different array. I want it so that with every cell I click on the first controller it displays a different but specific array each time.

When the Second View controller collection cell has been clicked it will then go to an view controller with a image, labels and text views were essentially I need to display a set of different data for each cell clicked.

I don't really know where to start, I believe it could be something to do with dictionaries but I have no clue where to start.

his is the code I am using for the first View controller with the collection view

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self

    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize{
          return CGSize(width: 160.0, height: 210.0)
       }


    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return labelArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        cell.imageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.item]
        cell.label.text = labelArray[indexPath.item]

        return cell
    }

}
```

I just don't know where to go from here, any help would be appreciated! 
Thank you[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIcFC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`. See [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618032-collectionview)

Inside it, you can call your segue, which navigates to next controller, e.g.:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Get selected row, you can then do something for each row
    let selectedRow = indexPath.row // can also get indexPath.section or .item
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "your identifier", sender: self)
}
```

If you want to pass some data from first controller to the next, you could pass a data in `override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryBoardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "your identifier" {
        var dest = segue.destinationViewController as! YourViewControllerType
        dest.anotherArray = ["whatever", "you", "want"]
}
```

Of course it's assumed that `YourViewControllerType` will have a member `var anotherArray: [String]?` (type and name can be changed of course).

A better way is to define a proper model class which will hold the data for destination controller.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I understand a bit more now, I just wanted to ask how would I, lets say, differentiate between the cells, so when I click each cell they will all do something different, that is just the last thing that I am struggling over. Thanks!

Comment: @StefanFletcher `indexPath` argument in `didSelectItemAt` provides you with row ID exactly as in `cellForItemAt ` method. So knowing row ID you can decide what to do. I will extend example slightly to show